# How to create silent .ogg audio file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, ogg

In answer to the question ["How-to make a silent mp3 or wav-file" on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911430) FakeOutdoorsman provided the following recipe:

> Another method by using FFmpeg. 60 seconds of silent audio in WAV:
>
> `ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t 60 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec copy output.wav`
>
> 60 seconds of silent audio in MP3:
>
> `ffmpeg -ar 48000 -t 60 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -acodec libmp3lame -aq 4 output.mp3`

How could I do something similar to create a silent .ogg audio file?

For a web app, I want to create a very short file for testing whether the browser will preload an audio file, or whether it will wait until the file is actually played before starting to stream it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify `-acodec` to be `vorbis` (instead of `libmp3lame`) and put `.ogg` at the end of the output file (in place of `.mp3`).

Comment: Thanks! I needed to use `libvorbis` instead of `vorbis`. The output for 30ms is 3,694 bytes. I can get a 30ms MP3 file for 333 bytes. At [wittnl's page on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/wittnl/8a1a0168b94f3b6abfaa) I found a dataURL for a silent ogg that is less than 300 bytes, including base64 encoding...

Comment: Nice. I'm glad you know how to fill in the blanks. About the size discrepancy you observed, I wager that FFmpeg probably writes a metadata block into the file and that the smaller file you found likely omits it.

Answer (score 17):

## Silent audio

That's an outdated method. You can now use the [`anullsrc` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) instead, and it will work on any OS:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -t 5 -c:a libvorbis output.ogg
```

- Default sample rate is 44100, and default channel layout is stereo. If you want something different you can do something like: `anullsrc=r=48000:cl=mono` (or use `cl=1` for mono).
- For Vorbis in general, avoid the native encoder `vorbis` if possible; `libvorbis` will provide a better output (although it doesn't really matter with a silent output).

---

## Other somewhat related examples

### Test tone

An annoying tone or beeping tone can be made with [`sine` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine). Generate a 220 Hz sine wave with a 880 Hz beep each second, for 5 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=f=220:b=4:d=5 -c:a libvorbis output.oga
```

### Just black video

Using the [`color` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc).

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=d=5 -c:v libtheora output.ogv
```

- Default frame rate is 25 and default video size is 320x240. To change it: `color=r=24:s=1280x720:d=5`.
- But who uses Theora anymore? A more modern alternative that likely fills its niche is VP8/VP9 + Vorbis in WebM: `-c:v libvpx output.webm`.

### Test pattern + 440 Hz tone

Using [`testsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) and `sine` filters:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc -f lavfi -i sine -t 10 -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis \
-q:v 5 -q:a 5 output.ogv
```

- Change frame rate and video size the same way as shown above for the `color` filter.
- See [FFmpeg Filter Documentation: Video Sources](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Sources) for a list of many other video source filters such as `smptehdbars`.

## Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: A Brief Theora and Vorbis Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg Codecs Documentation: libtheora](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libtheora)
- [FFmpeg Codecs Documentation: libvorbis](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libvorbis)
- [​Hydrogen Audio: Recommended Vorbis Encoder Settings](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Recommended_Ogg_Vorbis#Recommended_Encoder_Settings)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: VP8 Video in WebM Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8)

Comment: Thanks! Your command gives this output: `size= 4kB time=00:00:04.98 bitrate=7.3kbits/s video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 2004.608276%` Is it possible to create the .ogg file without any global headers, to get the minimum viable output file?

Comment: If you want to avoid problems when concatenating silence with other sounds, do create the silence with the SAME parameters than the sound you will mix with (mono/stereo and Hz).